# Kube-up.sh loops forever in specific AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I experience very strange behavior when I'm trying to set new Kubernetes cluster in AWS.

Whenever I try to run kube-up.sh with its default config it works perfectly,
The cluster and all its relative components are setting up in less than 10 minutes.

The problem occur when I set the "kube-aws-zone" to be us-east-1e (the same as my current VPC) instead of us-west-2a (default).
The installation process stuck in a loop with the following message-

> Waiting 3 minutes for cluster to settle ..................Re-running
>   salt highstate sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-20-0-9 Waiting for
>   cluster initialization.
>
> This will continually check to see if the API for kubernetes is
>   reachable.   This might loop forever if there was some uncaught error
>   during start   up.

I tried to dig a bit in the minions and find this error in /var/log/salt/minion

> 2015-10-01 14:52:54,912 [salt.loaded.int.module.cmdmod][ERROR   ]
>   Command 'runlevel /run/utmp' failed with return code: 1 2015-10-01
>   14:52:54,913 [salt.loaded.int.module.cmdmod][ERROR   ] output: Too
>   many arguments. 2015-10-01 14:53:00,902 [salt.state       ][ERROR   ]
>   The named service kubelet is not available 2015-10-01 14:53:03,078
>   [salt.state       ][ERROR   ] The named service kube-proxy is not
>   available 2015-10-01 14:53:16,677 [salt.state       ][ERROR   ] An
>   exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 1533, in
>   call
>       **cdata['kwargs'])   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/sysctl.py", line 56, in
>   present
>       configured = **salt**'sysctl.show'   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/linux_sysctl.py", line
>   86, in show
>       for line in salt.utils.fopen(config_file_path):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/**init**.py", line 1065,
>   in fopen
>       fhandle = open(*args, **kwargs) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/sysctl.d/99-salt.conf'
>
> 2015-10-01 14:53:16,707 [salt.loaded.int.module.cmdmod][ERROR   ]
>   Command 'runlevel /run/utmp' failed with return code: 1 2015-10-01
>   14:53:16,708 [salt.loaded.int.module.cmdmod][ERROR   ] output: Too
>   many arguments. 2015-10-01 14:53:16,719
>   [salt.loaded.int.module.cmdmod][ERROR   ] Command 'service docker
>   status' failed with return code: 3 2015-10-01 14:53:16,719
>   [salt.loaded.int.module.cmdmod][ERROR   ] output: * docker.service -
>   Docker Application Container Engine    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
>   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu
>   2015-10-01 14:53:16 UTC; 262ms ago
>        Docs: http://docs.docker.com   Process: 15285 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 15285 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Oct 01 14:53:16 ip-172-20-0-90 systemd[1]: docker.service: main
>   process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Oct 01 14:53:16
>   ip-172-20-0-90 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
>   Oct 01 14:53:16 ip-172-20-0-90 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
>   2015-10-01 14:53:20,259 [salt.state       ][ERROR   ] The named
>   service kubelet is not available 2015-10-01 14:53:20,687 [salt.state
>   ][ERROR   ] The named service kube-proxy is not available

I've tried to remove and re-set the IAM roles as suggested to similar issue, but ended up with no luck.

Will appreciate any assistance.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The problem was specific for us-east-1 region.
I had to edit the dhcp-set that was created as part of kube-up.sh and add the following -

> domain-name = ec2.internal

Then it worked like charm.

More information - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7962#issuecomment-145324441